# Issue defining Querydef parameters, run time error 13 type mismatch

Tags: vba, ms-access, parameters

I am wanting to open a recordset based on a query.  The query has 10 parameters that it matches to a form.  The parameters are a bit complex because they are searching for a partial string match.

I have run into multiple issues and it appears access won't let me open a recordset based on a query that pulls parameters from a form.  Instead I am now trying to open a querydef and pass that to a recordset.  I am getting a run time error 13 type mismatch when I try to run the function now.  Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?  Does anyone have any insight into fixing this error?  The error is highlighting the first parameter (export country) but if that one is a problem I am sure they all are.  Thanks!

*modified to try to pass conditional parameters through recordset instead

```
Function StatementUpdate()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rstStatements As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstCBG As DAO.Recordset
Dim concStatement As String
Dim strSQL As Variant


Set dbs = CurrentDb()
strSQL = "SELECT [Statement] FROM [St_Gen_Qry] WHERE" _
     & " (([Statement Category]='General Information')" _
     & " And ([Export Country] Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Export Country] & "*'" _
     & " Or [Export Country]='All')" _
     & " And ([Export State] Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Export State] & "*'" _
     & " Or [Export State]='All')" _
     & " And ([Import Country] Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Import Country] & "*'" _
     & " Or [Import Country]='All')" _
     & " And ([Import State] Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Import State] & "*'" _
     & " Or [Import State]='All')" _
     & " And ([Shipment Type] Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Shipment Type] & "*'" _
     & " Or [Shipment Type]='All')" _
     & " And ([Material Category] Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Material Category] & "*'" _
     & " Or [Material Category]='All')" _
     & " And ([Sub Category] Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Sub Category] & "*'" _
     & " Or [Sub Category]='All')" _
     & " And ([Transgenic/ Conventional] Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.RegCode & "*'" _
     & " Or [Transgenic/ Conventional]='All')" _
     & " And ([Intended Use] Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Intended Use] & "*'" _
     & " Or [Intended Use]='All')" _
     & " And ([Permit] Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Permit Required] & "*'" _
     & " Or [Permit]='All')" _
     & " And ([Active]='Yes'));"

Set rstStatements = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
Set rstCBG = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT Cross_Border_Grid_Table.ID,    Cross_Border_Grid_Table.St_General FROM Cross_Border_Grid_Table WHERE   (Cross_Border_Grid_Table.ID)= " & [Forms]![New_Shipment_Home_frm]![Text105])


rstCBG.MoveFirst

'loop through each record in the CBG that matches select query
Do Until rstCBG.EOF
    concStatement = ""
    rstStatements.MoveFirst
    Do Until rstStatements.EOF
        concStatement = concStatement & vbCrLf & rstStatements(0) & vbCrLf
        rstStatements.MoveNext
    Loop
        rstCBG.Edit
        rstCBG![St_General] = concStatement
        rstCBG.Update
        rstCBG.MoveNext
        Loop

rstCBG.Close
rstStatements.Close

Set rstStatements = Nothing
Set rstCBG = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing

Debug.Print "Done"

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is you are trying to pass a conditional expression in a querydef parameter. So, first `OR` in each parameter statement must be part of string where you have it outside as a VBA operator. Second, you need the `LIKE *` clause to search by string patterns. Then, you may need to wrap form values in single quotes. Maybe it is possible but querydef parameters usually take a single value not conditional expressions as you lay out.

With that said you could absolutely pass form values with dynamic conditional expressions in a VBA recordset (similar to other recordset by the way):

```
strSQL = "SELECT [Statement] FROM [St_Gen_Qry] WHERE" _
         & " (([Statement Category]='General Information')" _
         & " And ([Export Country] Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Export Country] & "*'" _
         & " Or [Export Country]='All')" _
         & " And ([Export State] Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Export State] & "*'" _
         & " Or [Export State]='All')" _
         & " And ([Import Country] Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Import Country] & "*'" _
         & " Or [Import Country]='All')" _
         & " And ([Import State] Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Import State] & "*'" _
         & " Or [Import State]='All')" _
         & " And ([Shipment Type] Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Shipment Type] & "'*" _
         & " Or [Shipment Type]='All')" _
         & " And ([Material Category] Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Material Category] & "*'" _
         & " Or [Material Category]='All')" _
         & " And ([Sub Category] Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Sub Category] & "*'" _
         & " Or [Sub Category]='All')" _
         & " And ([Transgenic/ Conventional] Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.RegCode & "*'" _
         & " Or [Transgenic/ Conventional] ='All')" _
         & " And ([Intended Use] Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Intended Use] & "*'" _
         & " Or [Intended Use]='All')" _
         & " And ([Permit Like '*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Permit Required] & "*'" _
         & " Or Permit='All') And (Active='Yes'))"

Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!  I am still getting a type mismatch on strSQL.  Here is the modified section of code.

Comment: Do not wrap `LIKE` statements in parentheses and you must include single quotes around form values and wildcard asterisks (`*`). Also be sure you put spaces after `WHERE`, `AND`, and `OR` when you break lines in VBA string. See my edit..

Comment: Thank you!  I think I'm very close.  I am still getting a run time 3075 error saying there is a missing operator in strSQL somewhere, but I will comb through and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I Spoke too soon, I figured out the operator issue, but I am now getting a run time 3061 error, too few parameters. Expected 2.  I clearly have way more than 2 parameters.  When I debug.print it seems the recordset is pulling the parameters in ok. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a field does not exist. Message box `strSQL` and read the query when it pops up to screen, checking if fields, syntax, punctuation are correct. If you see no issue, copy the `SELECT` query into Access' query designer (stripping out VBA quotes, ampersands, underscores), then run query there and a more detailed error message will appear.

Comment: It seems to be having trouble with the two parameters that have hard coded text (General Information and Yes).  It prompts for a parameter value on those parameters rather than taking what I have put in the code.

Comment: Epic overlook on my part as I used a different table alias than `St_Gen_Qry`. See update where I also removed redundant parentheses. Also, if Active is Yes/No (i.e., True/False) field, remove quotes around `Yes` since it is not a string. Do note you can save this query as a stored query and just call it in VBA recordset line. Optimizer caches and stores best query plan with stored queries vs VBA string queries, hence slightly more efficient.

Comment: Thank you!  One final question.  With the query parameters set up that way, Access seems to only be pulling in fields that match the "all" and not the partial string match.  Do you have any ideas on how I could make it recognize the partial string match as well?  Thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: You use the `OR` operator which adds to the partial string matches and 'All' would include everything. So there's overlap. Take out the 'All' condition to only return partial string matches. Also, please accept answerto mark as complete.